# What's the name of the runway equipment referred to in this video?

Tags: equipment

In [this Air Crash investigation video clip (31:06)](https://youtu.be/EOQj4uh4AB0?t=31m5s), a beacon system that tells the pilots whether the aircraft is laterally aligned with the designated runway is mentioned. What's its official name?

Comment: As this great documentation series also aims for people who are not into aviation, I think the "beacon" just refers to the localizer of the ILS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called the [Runway localizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_landing_system_localizer)

Comment: Oops. I thought it was some special equipment I was not familiar with. Thanks